# Spring ignores Entity annotation

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa

I'm having a problem when i try to create a table using Spring Boot any mysql it seems that Spring boot is not creating table,tried various solutions including:

I'm using windows 10,and in MySql Workbench for the current user all the privileges are granted.Even tried default:
root
root
and it doesnt work

```
@EntityScan(basePackage={""})
```

Here is my class:

```
@Entity
public class Student {

@Id
private long id;
private String firstName;
private String lastName;
private String email;
private int age;

public Student(){
    System.out.println("student executed");
}

public Student(long id, String firstName, String lastName, String email, int age) {
    this.id = id;
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
    this.email = email;
    this.age = age;
}

public long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getFirstName() {
    return firstName;
}

public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
}

public String getLastName() {
    return lastName;
}

public void setLastName(String lastName) {
    this.lastName = lastName;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}

public int getAge() {
    return age;
}

public void setAge(int age) {
    this.age = age;
}



@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Student{" +
            "id=" + id +
            ", firstName='" + firstName + '\'' +
            ", lastName='" + lastName + '\'' +
            ", email='" + email + '\'' +
            ", age=" + age +
            '}';
}
```

}

and application.properties:

```
   server.port=8080
spring.datasource.username=newuser
spring.datasource.password=
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/spring


spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.strategy=org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
```

starting application standard Spring boot way.

the Main Class:

```
@EntityScan("com.example.demo.models")
@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {



    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kyAtY.png)
Thanks for any tip.

Comment: what is the structure of your application? packages I mean

Comment: DemoApplication(which contains main method) is in:
com.example.demo
and Student(@Entity model) is in com.example.demo.models.

Comment: try with `@EntityScan("com.example.demo.models")`

Comment: tried already multiple times with different annotations but doesn't work

Comment: edit your question please and paste also the class that has @EntityScan

Comment: just edited the question

Comment: Have you tried also adding `@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {"com.eample.demo.*"})` ?

Comment: Yes,even changed the source folder location but nothing works.

Comment: try adding the following property in application.properties `spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver`

Comment: Nothing added a screenshot of terminal but nothing related .

Comment: Share you project through github

Answer (score -1):

I created a new project from Spring Initializr,and used Java 8 instead of Java 11,and it seems it worked,i did to update any maven dependency that i was having and re-checked for newest versions.
I'm having `java version "1.8.0_261"`
installed so thanks guys for your effort!